# Get Guid.Empty in controller and pass it to view

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, viewbag

I need to get Guid.Empty in controller and pass it to view.  I tried to use ViewBag, I added this code in my controller

```
public class QuestionnaireController : Controller
{
   //....
   ViewBag.EmptyGuid = Guid.Empty;
}
```

and added this code in view

```
if (rowobject[6] == ViewBag.EmptyGuid) { //...}
```

but I got some errors in controller
`Error  1   Invalid token '=' in class, struct, or interface member declaration`
`Error  2   Invalid token ';' in class, struct, or interface member declaration`

what's wrong and how to make it works?

**UPD**
I changed code in my controller (I added `ViewBag.EmptyGuid` inside method)

```
[HttpGet]
    public ActionResult QuestionnaireIndex()
    {
        ViewBag.EmptyGuid = Guid.Empty.ToString();
        FillViewBags();
        return View();
    }
```

and this is script in my view

```
@section scripts{

<script type="text/javascript"> function buttonize(cellvalue, options, rowobject) {
 var buttons = '';

 if (rowobject[5] == "False") {
     buttons += '<input type="button" value="Edit" onclick="editQuestionnaire(' + options.rowId + ')">';
 }

 buttons += '<input type="button" value="Delete" onclick="deleteQuestionnaire(' + options.rowId + ')">';

 if (rowobject[6] == ViewBag.EmptyGuid) {
     buttons += '<input type="button" value="Publish" onclick="publishQuestionnaire(' + options.rowId + ')">';
 }
 else {
     buttons += '<input type="button" value="Remove" onclick="removePublishQuestionnaire(' + options.rowId + ')">';
 }

 return buttons;
 }
</script>
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have code directly in the class, you need a method. For example:

```
public class QuestionnaireController : Controller
{
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        ViewBag.EmptyGuid = Guid.Empty;
        return View();
    {
}
```

This error really has nothing to do with MVC: that is invalid C# syntax and you're getting a compilation error.

On a side note - I'd recommend not using `ViewBag` at all (or almost ever) when you can use a strongly typed model. Same goes for `rowobject[6]`: I'm not sure what that is, but you definitely don't want data readers on your View. By the time the data is in the view, it should have already been converted to a model.
On the other hand, I don't think it is *wrong* to use `Guid.Empty` or `default(Guid)` on a view.

Comment: Yes, I have already found my mistake, but thanks you for help anyway, but now I cant get my `ViewBag.EmptyGuid` in view and I don't know what's wrong?

Comment: @Heidel - can you please update the question with the real code?

Comment: @Heidel - You shouldn't accept the answer if it didn't solve your problem. What exactly is wrong now? What doesn't work? If I hadto guess - it is *possible* the GUIDs are in different formats - e.g. `{12-3-4-5-abc}` vs `12345abc`.

Comment: Your answer solved the first part of my problem, and I found the solution of the second part myself - I was need to use in my view this code `if (rowobject[6] == '@ViewBag.EmptyGuid')`

Comment: @Heidel - Great! I missed that point... Glad I could help anyway.